# Comparing digits of two inputs to see if they are the same

Tags: c

I am currently trying to finish a code where a user inputs two 5 digit long numbers. The code then checks to see if there are any identical numbers in the same spot for the two numbers and displays how many identical numbers there are in the same spot of the two inputs. (ex. comparing 56789 and 94712 there would be one similar digit, the 7 in the 3rd digit place.) As of now I have been able to break down the inputs into the digits in each spot, I just need help comparing them. Originally I thought I could just create an int that would serve as a counter and use modulus or division to output a 1 whenever the digits were the same, but I have been unable to put together a formula that outputs a 1 or 0 depending on if the digits are alike or not.

Comment: Formula? Like `a==b`?

Comment: I would treat the inputs as strings and compare them character by character. Don't think you gain much by converting the inputs to `int`s

Comment: few similar questions in last days, is this assignment?

Comment: "I have been able to break down the inputs into the digits in each spot," --> post that code.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you know the length of strings `n` (as a condition you would need them to be equal, if they differ in length other validation is needed)

```
//n is the length of string
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(string1[i]==string2[i])
    {
      //do something, make a counter that increments here...
      //also save index i, so you can tell the position when a match occured
    }else 
    {
      //do something else if you need to do something when chars didnt match
    }
}
```

Here you when `i=0`, you are comparing `string1[0]` with `string2[0]`, when `i=1`, you compare `string1[1]` with `string2[1]` and so on.....

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading the two in as strings or converting to strings if you have the ability to. From there it's a simple string compare with a counter. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_numeric(char *str)
{
    while (*str)
        if (!isdigit(*str++))
            return (0);
    return (1);
}

int main(void)
{
    char    num1[32];
    char    num2[32];
    int     count = 0;

    printf("Digit 1\n>> ");
    if (scanf("%5s", num1) != 1 || !is_numeric(num1))
        return (0);
    printf("Digit 2\n>> ");
    if (scanf("%5s", num2) != 1 || !is_numeric(num2))
        return (0);
    if (strlen(num1) != 5 || strlen(num2) != 5)
        return (0);
    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        if (num1[i] == num2[i])
            ++count;
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it very easy using modulo (`%`) and divide (`/`). First you do `% 10` to get the least significant digit and do the compare. Then you do `/ 10` to remove the least significant digit. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int i1, i2;
    int i;
    int cnt = 0;
    printf("Input first 5 digit number:\n");
    if (scanf(" %u", &i1) != 1 || i1 < 10000 || i1 > 99999) // Get integer input and check the range
    {
        printf("input error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Input second 5 digit number:\n");
    if (scanf(" %u", &i2) != 1 || i2 < 10000 || i2 > 99999) // Get integer input and check the range
    {
        printf("input error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        if ((i1 % 10) == (i2 % 10)) ++cnt;      // Compare the digits
        i1 = i1 / 10;
        i2 = i2 / 10;
    }
    printf("Matching digits %d\n", cnt);    // Print the result
    return 0;
}
```

It can also be done using strings. Read the input as unsigned int and then convert the value to a string using `snprintf` and finally compare the two strings character by character.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str1[32];
    char str2[32];
    unsigned int i1, i2;
    int i;
    int cnt = 0;
    printf("Input first 5 digit number:\n");
    if (scanf(" %u", &i1) != 1)               // Get integer input
    {
        printf("input error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    snprintf(str1, 32, "%u", i1);
    if (strlen(str1) != 5)                    // Convert to string
    {
        printf("input error - not 5 digits\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Input second 5 digit number:\n");
    if (scanf(" %u", &i2) != 1)               // Get integer input
    {
        printf("input error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    snprintf(str2, 32, "%u", i2);                    // Convert to string
    if (strlen(str2) != 5)
    {
        printf("input error - not 5 digits\n");
        return 0;
    }


    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        if (str1[i] == str2[i]) ++cnt;      // Compare the characters
    }
    printf("Matching digits %d\n", cnt);    // Print the result
    return 0;
}
```

The reason for taking the input into a `unsigned int` instead of directly to a string is that by doing that I don't have to check that the string are actually valid numbers (e.g. the user type `12W34`). `scanf` did that for me.

Comment: It'd make more sense not to convert from raw input, `char *` to a numerical data type and then back to a `char *` for analysis. Calling `scanf(%u)` with the hopes of converting to a a string is more work than testing a string to ensure all chars are numerical.

Comment: @0x11 - More work? For you or the processor? For a program that takes user input from stdin performance is seldom an issue. Try to write the complete program with direct string input and make all checks needed. Do you get a shorter program?